# windows 7 backup resilient to hard drive/laptop death

Tags: windows-7, backup

I need to achieve a system (windows 7) backup that

- Is resilient to a hard drive death
- Even better, resilient to a laptop death

Is there a way i can restore a full backup on my windows7 on a different laptop / same laptop with different harddrive? If so, with what tool?

Thank u sooo much!!!

Comment: Is cloning the disk an option for you?

Comment: Sadly, I can't remove the drive away from the laptop

Comment: You can clone the HDD without removing it from the laptop. Use a different drive to boot from, such as an external USB attached HDD, SSD, or flash drive, with an OS and closing software on it.  Also note that Microsoft designs Windows not to migrate from one PC type to another unless you have Enterprise licensing, so you will see a prompt from them to re-register your OS if you restore onto a different model.

Comment: There is software that can restore a disc image to different hardware but your W7 will not activate on different hardware, so you would have to purchase a new licence/product key

Answer (score 1):

I think Acronis True Image would be a good solution here.  You can backup and restore to a computer with dissimilar hardware.  Macrium Reflect has a free version that might work as well but I'm not sure if you can restore to dissimilar hardware.

Comment: You need the paid version of Macrium Reflect to restore to dissimilar hardware https://knowledgebase.macrium.com/display/KNOW7/Re-deploying+Windows+to+new+hardware+using+Macrium+ReDeploy

Comment: any freeware tool?

Comment: Sadly, acronis backup throws a blue screen of death (bad driver) on different computer. Now, I wonder: If I clone the HD and restore the backuped HD on my laptop, will windows boot normally?